# What is difference between assignment with and without bit selector? (e/Specman)

Tags: integer, verification, specman, e

I'm coding in e (Specman) programming language. If I want to assign integer variable with constant, what is the difference if I use bit selector (selecting all 32 bits) or not?

I wanted to assign integer variable with negative constant in form: 32'b1... but this value was automatically cast to positive number (larger than MAX_INT) and I got the error. Then I tried using bit selector ([31:0]) on variable and assignment passed with no errors. Good number was assigned to variable. I'm not sure why is this case. What is the reason negative number is automatically cast when we don't use bit selector, and why not when we use it.

Code with error:

```
int_variable = 32'b111111111111111111111111
```

Code with no error:

```
int_variable[31:0] = 32'b111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? Binary constant is an unsigned integer, but the casting from unsigned to singed or back is automatic, unless happens in some special context. Using bit selector to workaround casting issues sounds like overkill, and might obscure some real problems.

Answer (score 1):

The docs say

> In an assignment (lhs = rhs), the right-hand side (rhs) expression
>   inherits the context of the left-hand side (lhs) expression

So your rhs expression should automatically be cast to -1 (assuming your code contains 32 or more 1's; for 31 1's you would get MAX_INT).

I don't think Specman gives an error for this.